# LibreOffice 5.0.1 crashes when it calls ODMRegisterApp function

Tags: interop, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I am using Libreoffice 5.0, I am trying to create a macro to save the file in my application, i get an error when we try to register odma in the function ODMRegisterApplication. please can someone tell me how to resolve this issue or is there any other alternative to accomplish this task

Answer (score 0):

It might help to post some of your code. Are you trying to call an external library (DLL or SO file) from a LibreOffice macro?

In my experience, using COM and OLE calls from LibreOffice is buggy.  An alternative using python is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353919/calling-c-shared-library-function-from-libreoffice-basic/32638710).