# (build) gcc/g++ with 32 bits libraries under ubuntu 15.04 (64-bits PC (AMD64) desktop image)

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, virtual-machine, 32bit-64bit, ubuntu-15.04

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 64-bits from the 64-bits [PC (AMD64) desktop image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/) in a VMWare image (I am under win7 64 bits), and I tried to build gcc 5.2 on it. At the configure step I had a couple of errors, like :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

They are I guess related to the apparent absence of the 32 bits libraries. In the same fashion, compiling with ubuntus g++ and the `-m32` option leads to

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

Looking for c++config.h gives me this :

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++config.h
```

I suspect the 32 libraries are mis-installed, as I have a folder `/usr/lib32` with only this :

```
xx@xx-ubuntu1504vm:/usr/lib32$ ls -l
total 1372
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  12288 août  20 11:00 gconv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 mars   6  2015 libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68012 mars   6  2015 libform.so.5.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112708 avril 15 04:06 libgcc_s.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 mars   6  2015 libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34548 mars   6  2015 libmenu.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 mars   6  2015 libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13584 mars   6  2015 libpanel.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 avril 14 22:15 libstdc++.so.6 ->     libstdc++.so.6.0.20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 975360 avril 14 22:51 libstdc++.so.6.0.20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 mars   6  2015 libtic.so.5 -> libtic.so.5.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  63160 mars   6  2015 libtic.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 oct.  27  2014 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 108080 oct.  27  2014 libz.so.1.2.8
```

in it.

What could I do ?

Comment: The keyword to google for is multiarch.

Comment: @MarcGlisse So, what is the difference between `amd64` (my ubuntu architecture) and `x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0` (my mac os x achitecture) that explains that I need, if I follow you, to build gcc with `--enable-multiarch` under ubuntu and without it under mac os yosemite to be able to compile code targeting 32 bits architecture ?

Comment: Apple does not care about space, they are happy to install very fat things. Ubuntu thinks your hard drive should be spared useless things. If you want to use 32 bits (why?), you can enable multiarch and install 32 bit packages on your system. If you want a 64-bit only gcc, you can build with --disable-multilib.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Ok, it makes sense. (I am quite new to all of this.) What to you mean exactly by enabling multiarch ? As for installing 32bits packages, as far as I saw, there's no "kosher" way to do it in ubuntu 15.04, as far as I know.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit for instance.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Installing `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib` (resp. `gcc-4.8-multilib` and `g++-4.8-multilib`) packages under Ubuntu (resp. Trisquel) and passing the --enable-multilib option to configure made my day. To answer your question : I wanted to use 32 bits libraries in order to compile a 32 bits version of shared library to be able to use it libreoffice's starbasic. Why this ? Because I thought it will solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353919/calling-c-shared-library-function-from-libreoffice-basic) that I also encoutered -- and that I didn't had under Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The 64-bit bits/c++config.h file is provided on 32-bit systems (and vice-versa) by installing the g++-multilib package, so you need to install that package either using Software Center, Synaptic, or via the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

This is just a dependency package that resolves to g++-4.8-multilib for the default gcc/g++ version, and in turn depends on lib64stdc++-4.8-dev (64-bit compilation on 32-bit) or libx32stdc++-4.8-dev (32-bit compilation on 64-bit) - it is these that contain the actual header files.

There is an equivalent set of packages for the plain C compiler gcc.